# Retrieve Latest 5 Facebook Wall Posts using Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

How can i retrieve the latest 5 wall posts from Facebook using JavaScript?

Comment: You should research yourself first and then post your findings/code, for people to help you.

Comment: I have researched but Facebook documentation and the lack of articles to show anything about this topic i could not find.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FB.api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/)

```
FB.api("/me/feed", {limit: 5}, function(data){
    // data is an array of feed posts...
});
```

Comment: it is returning 0 in data. Any suggestion please.